# Передача набора данных с сервера в браузер

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.x, request, render

Я передаю набор данных с сервера:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
....
context.update({
    'request': request,
    'model_class'  : model_class,
    'id': model_class.id,
    'coords_x': coords_x, # например, 40.982 (float)
    'coords_y': coords_y, # например, 50.982 (float)
    'icon': model_icon, # например, "http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126482.svg" (unicode)
})
return render(request, 'app/mypage.html', context)
```

в `app/mypage.html` данные приходят в странном виде. В числах `float` точка меняется на запятую, из-за чего скрипт не воспринимает его ни как строку, ни как число, и выдаёт ошибку не только при попытке обработать данные, но и при преобразовании во `float` или в `string`. Эту проблему можно обойти, передав в `context` не `coords_x`, а `str(coords_x)`, тогда точка сохранится и можно будет на клиенте преобразовать это в число. Но это выглядит странно. И я не могу решить проблему с `model_icon`: браузер не воспринимает строку url после двоеточия. Вызывается ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` Даже если убрать двоеточие из передаваемой строки, та же ошибка. Что нужно почитать, чтобы разобраться, почему так происходит?

Нерабочий кусочек из `app/mypage.html`:

```
        <div class='item_map'>
            {% leaflet_map "map" callback='map_init_point' %}  
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 'use strict';
            function map_init_point (map, options){ 
                var coords = [];
                coords.push(parseFloat({{ coords_x }}));
                coords.push(parseFloat({{ coords_y }}));
                if ({{ icon|safe }}){ // вот эта строка никак не хочет работать
// в консоли браузера она выглядит как 
// if (image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/46/46045.svg){ ,
// а переменная должна быть в кавычках
                    var Point_Icon = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'http://' + {{ icon|safe }},
                        iconSize: [20, 20],
                        iconAnchor: [10, 10],
                    });
                    L.marker(coords, {icon: Point_Icon}).addTo(map);
                } else {
                    L.marker(coords).addTo(map);
                }
                map.setView({{ center }}, {{ zoom }}-3);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.print();
                }, 2000);
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django отдал содержимое строки. Кавычек в нём нет, поэтому и в скрипт переменная передаётся без кавычек. Решений тут несколько.

1) передать в `context` переменную, обёрнутую в кавычки.

`'icon': '"'+model_icon+'"',`

2) обернуть полученную переменную в кавычки уже в шаблоне. `if ("{{ icon|escapejs }}"){` В контекст при этом передаётся просто `'icon': model_icon,`

Answer (score 1):

Почитать можно про [автоматическое экранирование](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/templates/language.html#automatic-html-escaping)

А то, что точка заменяется на запятую, то возможно для повышения читабельности джанга что-то делает, но операции, тем не менее, должны быть доступны как с нормальным числом.

По-умолчанию в Django, каждый шаблон экранирует все переменные. В частности выполняются такие замены:

```
< заменяется на &lt;

> заменяется на &gt;

' (одинарная кавычка) заменяется на &#39;

" (двойная кавычка) заменяется на &quot;

& заменяется на &amp;
```

Для отключения авто-экранирования для отдельных переменных, используйте фильтр safe:

```
This will be escaped: {{ data }}
This will not be escaped: {{ data|safe }}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/103908)

Comment: Сейчас поправлю, автор просто спрашивал, что почитать.

Comment: могли бы в комментарии написать. репутация позволяет

Comment: @МистерФикс |safe не работает. В icon нет экранированных символов.

`if ({{ icon|safe }} != ''){` выдаёт в браузере строку:

`if (http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126482.svg != ''){`

и ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Напишите без if, нормально.

Comment: @МистерФикс `console.log(typeof ({{ icon|safe }}));` выдаёт строку `console.log(typeof (image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126482.svg));` и ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Ну покажите тогда ваш шаблон, что ли.

Comment: @МистерФикс , добавлен в текст вопроса.

Comment: Ну джано тут не при чём. Строку он вам отдал, дальше это вы уже с джаваскриптом ковыряйтесь. От меня подсказка: если вы хотите отдать джаваскрипту как "строку" то экранируйте вручную кавычки внутри строки. Например "\"string\"" или "'string'"